# How to have an array parameters using sanitize_text_field and update_post_meta in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple meta boxes that I need to save. I have able to save it but I think it is not the best way. I want something just one line code of update_post_meta and one line code of sanitize_text_field  to save multiple meta values. But now, currently I have 3 lines of code for sanitize_text_field and 3 lines of code for update_post_meta in order to save multiple meta boxes values. How can I optimize my code so that the 3 lines of my code could be just one line or how can I utilize array parameters for this functions? Here are my codes. Thanks for the help

```
// Sanitize user input.
 $mydata = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field']);
 $myskills_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['skills_id']);
 $myknowledge_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['knowledge_id']);

// Update the meta field in the database.
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $mydata );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_skills', $myskills_data );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_knowledge', $myknowledge_data );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should structure your text field names and meta keys in a more uniform fashion, for example:

```
$array = array( 'new_field', 'skills', 'knowledge' );

foreach( $array as $key )
{
    if( isset( $_POST[$key] ) )
    {
        $value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$key] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_' . $key, $value );
    }
}
```

this would store the sanitized data with meta keys `_my_meta_value_new_field`, `_my_meta_value_skills`, and `_my_meta_value_knowledge`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do anything else because your current code is not to much but if you really want to reduce a bit and want to make it a little dynamic then one way you can do it, just give it a try

```
$keys = array(
    '_my_meta_value_key' => 'myplugin_new_field', 
    '_my_meta_value_skills' => 'skills_id',
    '_my_meta_value_knowledge' => 'knowledge_id'
);
foreach($keys as $key => $value){
    if( isset($_POST[$value]) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $key , sanitize_text_field($_POST[$value]));
    }
}
```